# Error in Asp.MVC4 application. an UN-handled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my profile page. Controller is down there. I want to go to profile if login successful and want to go to resign in page if it is not successful. please suggest me answers.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile!";
}


<script src="~/Scripts/Profile.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Profile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form" name="form-CreateGroup" action="/CreateGroup/CreateGroup/@Model.Uid" method="post">
    <div>

        <input type="submit" id="CreateGroup" name="CreateGroup" value="Create Group" /><p> <span id="comments">Create your own groups.</span></p>

    </div>
</form>

<form class="form" name="form-SearchGroup" action="/Profile/SearchGroup" method="post">
    <div>

        <input type="submit" id="SearchGroup" name="SearchGroup" value="Search Group" /><p> <span id="comments">Search Groups to join them.</span></p>

    </div>
</form>

<form class="form" name="form-ViewGroups" action="/Profile/ViewGroups" method="post">
    <div>

        <input type="submit" id="ViewGroup" name="ViewGroup" value="View Groups" /><p> <span id="comments">View Groups you have already joined.</span></p>

    </div>
</form>

<form class="form" name="form-DeleteGroup" action="/Profile/DeleteGroup" method="post">
    <div>

        <input type="submit" id="DeleteGroup" name="DeleteGroup" value="Delete Group" /><p> <span id="comments">Delete Groups you are managing.</span></p>

    </div>
</form>
```

This is my Controller in which i want to lead to profile if account exist and lead to resign in if account does not exist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Project_Buddy.Models;

namespace Project_Buddy.Controllers
{
    public class SignInController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Signip/
        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult SignIn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult validation()
        {
            var email =Request["email"];
            var pas = Request["password"];
            IQueryable<User> record=null;
            record = (db.Users.Where(x=>x.email==email));
            if (record==null)
            {
                return Redirect("/ReSignIn/ReSignIn");

            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Profile/Profile");
            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: use RedirectToAction()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ReSignIn and Profile are tow different controllers, you can try the following:

```
public ActionResult validation()
{
    var email = Request["email"];
    var pas = Request["password"];
    IQueryable<User> record = null;
    record = (db.Users.Where(x => x.email == email));
    if (record == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ReSignIn", "ReSignIn");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy!!